# How does the hardware realize adding 8 values in 1 clock cycle?

Tags: vhdl, hardware, synthesis, asic

For example:

result= a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8

- How many adders are needed to perform this in 1 clock cycle?
- What does the design look in terms of hardware?

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. What have you done so far, where are you stuck? We can give you a nudge in the right direction, but we prefer not to give full homework answers, because we want the next generation of engineers to be capable.

Comment: Since an adder is combinatorial device, it doesn't need a clock. But it does have a signal propagation delay. As a result, it may demand some kind of pipeline (adding stages with registers) in order to comply with timing requirements, if present. So the question "How many adders are needed to perform this in 1 clock cycle?" doesn't make sense to me. Can it be a trick question?

Comment: Hello, it is a part of the bigger design. In which I am trying to design an architecture to reduce the number of cycles used for the algorithm. And it is result<= a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8 which I ignored. I know adders are combinational circuit and the result which is stored in a register after addition usually takes 1 cc.

Answer (score 2):

Since your tags indicate you're looking for a VHDL solution:

you'd just literally type

```
result := a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8
```

in your VHDL design and let the synthesizer and technology mapper take care of it – "how does one do this in hardware" is answered by knowing what kind of hardware is available; you'd almost never do the obvious undergrad-homework approach of building a tree adder for hardware: FPGAs don't contain "two-input adders" at all (aside from DSP slices, which you really don't want here, I guess), and ASICs are made from standard cells, some of which might be really useful here.

However, synthesizers and technology mappers differ in quality. Do try placing parentheses to help the synthesizer partition this in smaller problems and see whether a 2-partitioning or 4-partitioning helps.

Anyway, you *really* can't tell how the design will look like in hardware without specifying for which kind of hardware you're doing this, so your second question only has the answer "you'll know after elaboration of the design, and no earlier".

Comment: Unless my memory is failing me even worse than usual tonight (though at my age, that's a routine occurrence), that should really be: `result <= a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8`

Comment: @JerryCoffin My memory says VHDL uses *:=* and not *=*. Also, if there's no rising or falling edge involved in the begin..end block, then they are mapped equivalently, I think. Without the context, it's hard to argue one way or another. (Though I suspect a rising/falling edge somewhere, so I think they aren't the same.)

Comment: VHDL use both := and <= : according to whether `result` is a variable or a signal (= inter-process communication channel); the different symbol serves to remind the reader of the different semantics and timings.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Agreed about the variable/signal declaration part. Still, assuming a1, b1, c1, and y1 are on the port list, then I believe that "process(a1, b1, c1) variable m1: std_logic; begin m1 := a1 and b1; y1 <= m1 or c1; end process" produces the same combinatorial logic as "process(a1, b1, c1, m2) signal m2: std_logic; begin m2 <= a1 and b1; y1 <= m1 or c1; end process". So different ways of expressing the same logic production exist. Where it really gets my attention is when I see these within a rising of falling edge block. Then it's a world of difference between the two.

Comment: @jonk : the second approach (assuming some connection from m1 to m2)  produces a result in 2 delta cycles (or 3 if the connection is an external assignment to m1) in simulation. This can produce simulation differences if clock edges are a delta cycle apart! (and rightly so : that's fragile design)  You are correct that synthesis will probably generate the same gates.

Comment: Thank you! I do not much experience in design synthesis. I have a question: There seems to be a lot of grey area when it comes to synthesizes of variables in VHDL. Is it advisable to use them or not?

Comment: @Vishalbk um, no, there's no "grey area"; it might just be confusing. So, yes, use them, but understand when!